# Where is `contenttypes.generic.recent` coming from in record.twig?

Tags: bolt-cms

I was just going thorugh the following lines of code in the bolt CMS default theme.

```
{% for ct in app.config.get('contenttypes') if not ct.viewless|default(false) %}

            {% setcontent records = ct.slug ~ "/latest/3" %}

            <h5>{{ __('contenttypes.generic.recent', {'%contenttypes%': ct.slug}) }}</h5>
            <ul>
                {% for record in records %}
                    <li><a href="{{ record.link }}">{{ record.title }}</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li>{{ __('contenttypes.generic.no-recent', {'%contenttype%': ct.slug}) }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            <p><a href="{{ paths.root }}{{ct.slug}}">{{ __('contenttypes.generic.overview',{'%contenttypes%': ct.slug}) }} &raquo;</a></p>

        {% endfor %}
```

Now the below line of code:

```
        <h5>{{ __('contenttypes.generic.recent', {'%contenttypes%': ct.slug}) }}</h5>
```

Generates the follownng text in the front end :

```
Recent Pages

Recent Entries

Recent Showcases
```

But where exactly is `contenttypes.generic.recent` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

\vendor\bolt\bolt\app\resources\translations\en_GB\messages.en_GB.yml

In the file there is an entry

```
contenttypes.generic.recent: "Recent %contenttypes%"
```